# Install and run jupyterlab from src code as default

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have made a few changes to the `jupyterlab` code and I want to install and run this version as the default version on my machine.

According to the instructions I did the following:

```
pip install -e .
jlpm install
jlpm run build
jplm run build:core
jupyter lab build
```

The build is showing:
`[LabBuildApp] Building in /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab`

When I run jupyter lab, I can see that the application is running from there:
`[LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab`

But this build is not from my src code. Only when I run with the --dev-mode tag I can see the changes I made in the code (the change was specifically in the packages).

How do I build `jupyterlab` from the src (including the packages) and have this be the version always to run on my machine? I feel that I am missing a step in the process.